# Unable to launch from end to end Spring batch Job using groovy/spock - integration testing

Tags: groovy, junit, spring-batch, spock

I have recently start doing groovy testing in order to test a spring batch job that is using one step (ItemReader, ItemProcessor, ItemWriter)

Knowing that I am using h2 memory database, I have tried to launch the job also the step via the unit test, I am unable to verify that job has been completed:

```
    def 'test launch job'() {
    given:
    def projectId = 1234L
    def fileType = FileType.TEST
    def sourceId = 1234506L
    def enteredBy = 'groovy_unit_test'
    def prePlanYear = 2022L

    when:
 
    JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    builder.addLong("projectId", projectId)
            .addString("fileType", fileType.toString())
            .addLong("sourceId", sourceId)
            .addString("enteredBy", enteredBy)
            .addLong("prePlanYear", prePlanYear)
    //JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.launchJob( builder.toJobParameters())
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.launchStep(JobConstants.StepNames.xwalkMappingStep.name(), builder.toJobParameters())
  then: 'Job completes with no errors.'
   jobExecution.status == BatchStatus.COMPLETED
   //jobExecution.exitStatus == ExitStatus.COMPLETED
}
```

the status of the job always remains STARTED:
[image]

Also, When I tried to debug it does not go from end to end, it stop in the ItemReader once the test has finished. I see that it doesn't wait for the job to be completed.

Is there a Way to complete the test only after the job has finished?

```
@PropertySource('classpath:application.properties')
@ActiveProfiles('test')
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = ["spring.h2.console.enabled=true"])
@ImportAutoConfiguration([ FeignAutoConfiguration.class])
@Import([TestConfig.class])
class BaseSpec extends Specification{

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager

    @Autowired
    JobRepository jobRepository

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource

    @Autowired
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager

    @Autowired
    JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncher

}

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
class TestConfig {
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you did not run the entire job, but only its step here:

```
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.launchStep(JobConstants.StepNames.xwalkMappingStep.name(), builder.toJobParameters())
```

You should run the job with `JobLauncher#launchJob` and not only the step.

Comment: Hello @Mahmoud Ben Hassine,
Thank you for your response, I have also tried to run the job using: JobLauncherTestUtils
and I have faced the same issue. the expected result get verified before the job is completed.

Comment: In this case, you should have an *asynchronous* taskExecutor set in your JobLauncher. Make sure to use a synchronous TaskExecutor (which is the default) to ensure the step/job is finished before the assertion.

Comment: Thank you @Mahmoud Ben Hassine I will try it.